# Rotate a circle with 30deg when a key is pressed

Tags: javascript

Im trynig to make a circle with some text inside it rotate with 30deg for every time i press a button - I wrote the following code

```
<script>
    let margin = 40;
    let rotate = 30;
    let circle = document.getElementById("circle");

    document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {



    circle.style.transform = "rotate("+rotate+"deg)";
    });
  </script>
```

However my problem is that i want to make the circle keep rotating, every time i press a button. Right now it only works when i press a single time. So the code needs to loop some kind of way i guess.

Comment: Save a rotation in a variable. Add 30 every time you click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must increase the value by 30 each time when event `keypress` is called. Event `keypress` is no longer recommended so you should change it to `keyup` or `keydown`.

```
let margin = 40;
let rotate = 30;
let circle = document.getElementById("circle");

document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    circle.style.transform = "rotate("+rotate+"deg)";
    rotate += 30;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the rotate value…

```
<script>
let margin = 40;
let rotate = 30;
let circle = document.getElementById("circle");

document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => 
{
   circle.style.transform = "rotate("+rotate+"deg)";
   rotate+=30;
});
```